# $33^{33}$ is the sum of $33$ consecutive odd numbers. Which one is the largest? (Q25 from AMC 2012)

Tags: algebra-precalculus, elementary-number-theory, summation, contest-math

> The number $33^{33}$ can be expressed as the sum of $33$ consecutive odd numbers. The largest of these odd numbers is
>
> $\mathrm{A.}\ 33^{32} +32$
>
> $\mathrm{B.}\ 33^{31} +32$
>
> $\mathrm{C.}\ 33^{32} -32$
>
> $\mathrm{D.}\ 33^{31} -32$
>
> $\mathrm{E.}\ 33^{32}$

So no calculator is allowed, when I tried using the calculator,the answer is A.Why is it so and is there another way to do this question without using the calculator?

Comment: "... no calculator is allowed, when I tried using the the calculator, ..." ... really?

Comment: It was given by my teacher as practice for the holidays,so I tried without calculator using alegbra and I couldn't get anyway.So,it was my last resort...

Comment: Try taking the smallest number as $2k+1$, Now there are $33$ consecutive odd numbers, the sum of which is given, form an equation and you can calculate $k$ and get the last odd number.

Comment: The last odd number should be $2k+67$ right? Then where do I go from there? $ 2k+1+....2k+67 =33^{33} $ ?

Comment: @ArcNeoepi It should be $2k+65$

Comment: Oh sorry my mistake.

$2k+1+(33-1)(2)=2k+65$

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The average of those $33$ consecutive odd numbers is $33^{33}/33=33^{32}$. And $16$ of them are larger than the average, so the largest is...

Comment: So by this way, $33^{32} +16(2) $ Wow ,that's a interesting way!
So,the smallest in this case is $33^{32} -32 $ by does it add up to $33^{33}$ ?

Comment: Yes, but only because in this case the mean is the same as the median!

Comment: So,if the mean is equal to the median,the numbers will all add up,for whatever numbers?

Comment: @ArcNeoepi If in a distribution of values the mean equals the median, then exactly half of the population will be larger than the mean value (which is the property that defines the median). If the distribution is assymetric it can happen that the mean is lower or higher than the median. Think for example about the average income of a person. Since there are a few but very rich people, the mean is higher than the median, meaning that more than half of the population earns less than the average wage! (Example: 3 people, two earn 1, one earns 1000. Mean = $1002/3=  334$, median = $1$.

Answer (score 3):

$33^{33}=33\times 33^{32}+(-32-30-\cdots -2-0+2+\cdots +30+32)=$

$(33^{32}-32)+(33^{32}-30)+\cdots + (33^{32})+\cdots +(33^{32}+30)+(33^{32}+32)$

As $33^{32}$ is an odd number, then $(33^{32}\pm 2k)$ is odd as well. So, the largest one is $(33^{32}+32)$.

Comment: Ohhhh,okay,I finally understand!!! Thanks for the help!!! Thank you so much!!!

Comment: You are welcome @ArcNeoepi

Comment: @Majid you are making a mistake, the supposed equality is not such! Where are all those $33^{33}$ coming from? If you count, you will see that you have $33$ different $33^{33}$, which makes for $33\cdot 33^{33}=33^{34}$. That's why you should put $33^{32}$ instead.

Comment: @JoseBrox That was a good point! I appreciate your attention to my answer. I made the revision.

Answer (score 3):

First we prove that $1+3+5+\ldots +(2n-1) = n^2$ by induction:

The base case $2\cdot 1-1=1=1^1$ holds. Suppose the claim is true for $n$. Then $1+3+\ldots + 2(n+1)-1 = (1+\ldots +2n-1)+(2n+1) = n^2+2n+1 = (n+1)^2$, as desired.

Now, starting at number $m$, we have that $(m+1)+(m+3)+\ldots+(m+2\cdot 33-1)=33^{33}$. Hence $33m+33^2=33^{33}$, and therefore $m=33^{32}-33$ and so the last number is $m+2\cdot 33-1 = 33^{32}+33-1 = 33^{32}+32$.

Comment: Okay,I haven't learned induction yet so I'm lost,I don't understand the second paragraph second line.Can explain it to me?Sorry!

Comment: @ArcNeoepi Ok! Induction is a very powerful technique to prove identities and claims similar to the one you are asking, when you suspect beforehand what the answer should be. For example in this case, if you add $1+3=4$, $1+3+5=9$, $1+3+5+7=16$, you may notice that each sum of odd numbers gives you the next square number ($4=2^2, 9=3^2$, and so on). To make a proof by induction, you need two things: to see that there is a first case (the base case) in which your identity holds, and to show that if your identity is true for $n$, then it is also true for $n+1$. That's what I have done.

Comment: Why is it till $1+2+3+....+(2n-1)$ instead of $n-1$ ? Is it something like a formula?

Comment: @ArcNeoepi If you look carefully, you will see that the sum is over _odd_ numbers, $1+3+5+7+\ldots$ and, how do we represent an odd number? One useful way is to write $2n-1$ for the $n$-th odd number, starting with $n=1$. To see this, check that if $n=1$ then $2n-1=1$, if $n=2$ then $2n-1=3$, if $n=3$ then $2n-1=5$, and so on. This works for generating all odd numbers because since $2n$ is even, $2n-1$ is odd, and between $2n-1$ and $2(n+1)-1=2n+1$ there is no other odd number.

Comment: Thanks! I learned more than I could hope for today!Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2):

The sum of an arithmetic series is $\frac n2(a+l)$, where $n$ is the number of terms and $a$ and $l$ are the first and last terms respectively. You can think of it as the number of terms multiplied by the arithmetic means (simple average) of the bounding terms.

Here, $n=33$ and $l = a+(33-1)(2) = a + 64$ so the sum is $\frac{33}{2}(a + a + 64) = 33(a+32)$. Equating that to $33^{33}$, we find that $a + 32 = 33^{32}$, giving $l = a + 32 + 32 = 33^{32} + 32$.

Answer (score 1):

We have $x-32,x-30,\ldots,x,\ldots,x+30,x+32$ and thus $33x = 33^{33}$. Thus, the largest number is $33^{32}+32$.

Comment: Sorry,can you explain it ?I don't understand it,why $x-32$ at the start?

Comment: @ArcNeoepi just for symmetry, to simplify computing the sum.

Comment: could you explain why the numbers are consecutive?

Comment: The question said the numbers are consecutive odd numbers.

Comment: @Hagen von Eitzen,if it is for symmetry,wouldn't is be $x-32,x-30,....,x,...,x+30,x+32$ ?

Comment: @ArcNeoepi Sorry, that was a typo.

Comment: @ArcNeoepi I asked Puzzled417 to explain why his numbers are consecutive.

Comment: @Majid If you add $x-32$ with $x+32$ you do not get $0$, you get $2x$!